# using lm(poly) to get formula coeff

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to using lm(poly) to get a polynomial regression for some points, but got some questions about the regression formula coefficients it returns.

sample like this:

```
x=seq(1,100)
y=x^2+3*x+7
fit=lm(y~poly(x,2))
```

Results are:

`lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))`

Coefficients:

```
(Intercept)  poly(x, 2)1  poly(x, 2)2  
       3542        30021         7452
```

Why are the coefficients not 7,3,2?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try this: `lm(y~x+I(x^2))` or `lm(y~poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE))`.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Oups was not aware so let's close this question then

Comment: Danger! Danger, Will Robinson:::  If you are using the polynomial regression for inferential purposes, then using the raw variables will be very misleading.

Comment: @42- can you explain why, or link to an explanation?

Comment: Look up “orthogonal polynomials”.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the `raw` argument to TRUE of you don't want to use orthogonal polynomial
which is the default

```
set.seed(101)
N <- 100
x <- rnorm(N, 10, 3)
epsilon <- rnorm(N)
y <- 7 + 3 * x + x^2 + epsilon

coef(lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)))

##             (Intercept) poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)1 
##                  7.8104                  2.7538 
## poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)2 
##                  1.0150
```

From the help of the `poly` function you have

> Description:
>
> ```
>  Returns or evaluates orthogonal polynomials of degree 1 to
>  ‘degree’ over the specified set of points ‘x’. These are all
>  orthogonal to the constant polynomial of degree 0.  Alternatively,
>  evaluate raw polynomials.
> ```

And

> raw: if true, use raw and not orthogonal polynomials.

But you can also use what Ferdinand proposed, it works.

```
coef(lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)))
## (Intercept)           x      I(x^2) 
##      7.8104      2.7538      1.0150
```